# How can I find average mark

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Sorry if I don't write good, it's my first post. I have a problem with one task.

I have a test for a class and I want to know the average results for the class. Write a function that takes an array of hash with all of the grades/marks for a given test and returns an average grade for the entire class. Input are in JSON

```
function my_average_mark(param_1) {    
let total = 0
let result = 0;
    for (const key of param_1) {
    if (param_1.length > 0){
        total += (key['integer'])
        result=(total/param_1.length)   
    }
}
return result.toFixed(1)
};
```

These checks are successful

1)

```
Input: [
        {"string": "John", "integer": 7},
        {"string": "Margot", "integer": 8},
        {"string": "Jules", "integer": 4},
        {"string": "Marco", "integer": 19}
       ]

Output: 9.5
```

2. Input: []
   Output: 0.0

But I have trouble with this `Input: {}` - I get TypeError: param_1 is not iterable

Comment: Your sample data is weird, it should be `{name: "John", mark: 7},` instead of  `{"string": "John", "integer": 7},`

Answer (score 1):

Sum up all the `integer` values, and after the loop is done, divide them by the length of the array:

```js
function my_average_mark(param_1) {
  let total = 0;
  
  if(!param_1.length) return 0;
  
  for (const obj of param_1) {
    total += obj.integer;
  }

  return total / param_1.length;
}

const Input = [{"string":"John","integer":7},{"string":"Margot","integer":8},{"string":"Jules","integer":4},{"string":"Marco","integer":19}]

const result = my_average_mark(Input);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It does not work when I have - Input: [] and - Input: {}  In these cases Output must be 0.0

Comment: I've added a condition that will return 0 if length is 0 or doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much fot your help!

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant & concise way is using `.reduce` to aggregate the *total mark*. After that, divide it into *total students* like below.

```js
var my_average_mark = (data) => {
  if(!Array.isArray(data) || data.length === 0)
    return 0;
    
  var totalMark = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    acc += curr["integer"];
                    return acc;
                 }, 0)
  return totalMark/data.length;
}

var data = [{"string": "John", "integer": 7}, {"string": "Margot", "integer": 8},{"string": "Jules", "integer": 4}, {"string": "Marco", "integer": 19}];

 console.log(my_average_mark(data));
 console.log(my_average_mark([]));
 console.log(my_average_mark({}));
```

**Note:**

- Your sample data is weird, it should be `{name: "John", mark: 7}` instead of `{"string": "John", "integer": 7}`
- In the case of the input is `[]` or `{}`, you should check the type of input like ``

  ```
   if(!Array.isArray(data) || data.length === 0)
    return 0;
  ```

Comment: It does not work when I have - Input: [] and - Input: {}  In these cases Output must be 0.0

Comment: I've just updated my answer,pls take a look at :)

Comment: Thank you very much fot your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem -> loop is trying to get new result every time it is having new iteration
2. Solution -> keep result calculation outside loop